# How can I detect if the JSON object within Request body is empty in Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-web

I want to return an error when the body of a REST request is empty (e.g contains only `{}`) but there is no way to detect if the request body contains an empty JSON or not.

I tried to change `@RequestBody(required = true)` but it's not working.

```
@PatchMapping("{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Book> updateAdvisor(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, 
   @Valid @RequestBody  BookDto newBook) {
    Book addedBook = bookService.updateBook(newBook);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(addedBook,HttpStatus.OK);
  }
```

If the body sent contains an empty JSON I should return an exception.
If the body is not empty and at least one element is provided I won't return an error.

Comment: add validations on `BookDto`

Comment: Obviously {} is a valid BookDto, so you have to implement a custom validator OR set composite not null constraint on the database columns... which should exist either way... for data integrity (and propagate the constraint violation exception)

Comment: @AlekseiMaide what do you mean by composite notnull constraints? (is it just annotate all fields with NotNull annotation ?) 
if this is the case it's not a solution because user can input only few params to edit the book he is not obliged to input all params.

Comment: @KareemDev composite constraint on multiple database fields... eg. constraint book.name is not null OR book.description is not null ... and so on. (Create a constraint in the database that would check that insertable row contains at least one non null value) I dont know which database you are using, so i can't really help you with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `@RequestBody(required = false)`

This should cause the `newBook` parameter to be null when there is no request body.

The above still stands and is the answer to the original question.

To solve the newly edited question:

1. Change the `@RequestBody BookDto newBook` parameter to a String parameter
   (for example, `@RequestBody String newBookJson`).
2. Perform pre-conversion validation (such as, "is the body an empty JSON string value").
3. If the body contains valid JSON,
   parse the JSON into to an object (example below).

```
@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper; // A Jackson ObjectMapper.

@PatchMapping("{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Book> updateAdvisor(
  @PathVariable("id") Integer id, 
  @Valid @RequestBody String newBookJson)
{
  if (isGoodStuff(newBookJson)) // You must write this method.
  {
    final BookDto newBook = ObjectMapper.readValue(newBookJson, BookDto.class);

    ... do stuff.
  }
  else // newBookJson is not good
  {
    .. do error handling stuff.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you have a Class BookDto :

```
 public class BookDto {
       private String bookName;
       private String authorName;
  }
```

We can use **@ScriptAssert** Annotation on Class BookDto:

```
@ScriptAssert(lang = "javascript", script = "_this.bookName != null || _this.authorName != null")
public class BookDto {
       private String bookName;
       private String authorName;
  }
```

then in the resource/controller Class:

```
@PatchMapping("{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Book> updateAdvisor(@PathVariable("id") Integer id, 
   @Valid @RequestBody  BookDto newBook) {
    Book addedBook = bookService.updateBook(newBook);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(addedBook,HttpStatus.OK);
  }
```

Now @Valid annotation will validate whatever we have asserted in the **@ScriptAssert** annotation's script attribute. i.e it now checks if the body of a REST request is empty (e.g contains only {}).